# Adding new series for each row of data to a stacked column chart using a loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to add new series for each new row of data that I enter I want the name of the series to be in column B and the values to be in columns E to AH. The counter to loop from 71-206 and the j variables accounts for the title and other offsets so I am matching the series to its data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub stacked()
'
' stacked Macro
'
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 71 To 206
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    j = i + 5
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = "=Sheet1!B" & j
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = "=Sheet1!E:AH" & j ":AH"&j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Its the activechart values line. I should read `"=Sheet1!E" & j & ":AH" & j`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub stacked()
'
' stacked Macro
'
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 71 To 206
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
j = i + 5
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = "=Sheet1!B" & j
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = "=Sheet1!E" & j & ":AH" & j
Next i

End Sub
```

Minor error, that's all!